# Rails: How to validate password from input if there is not password field in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have table with fields: `email`, `password_hash` and `salt`.

On user registration, I want to validate password and password confirmation, but I always get error that says `can't be blank` for password input.

This is my model:

```
attr_accessor :password

validates :password, :presence     => true,
                     :confirmation => true,
                     :length       => { :within => 6..40 }
```

I guest I can't validate field that is not it the database, but how to make validation on password that user enters?

I don't have password field in database because I encypt that `password` input I get and then I store it in db `password_hash` field.

**EDIT :**

This is database table:

```
class CreateStudents < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :students do |t|
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.string :email
      t.string :password_hash
      t.string :salt

      t.boolean :activated

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

This is the view for registration:

```
<%= form_for @student, url: {action: 'create'} do |form| %>

  <p style="font-size:smaller; color:red">
  <% @student.errors.messages.each do |att, msg| %>
    <%= msg[0] %><br>
  <% end %>
  <p>
  <%= form.label :first_name %><br>
  <%= form.text_field :first_name %>
  <p>
  <%= form.label :last_name %><br>
  <%= form.text_field :last_name %>
  <p>
  <%= form.label :email %><br>
  <%= form.text_field :email %>
  <p>
  <%= form.label :password %><br>
  <%= form.password_field :password %>
  <p>
  <%= form.label :password_confirmation %><br>
  <%= form.password_field :password_confirmation %>
  <p>
  <%= form.submit %>

<% end %>
```

This is the controller:

```
def sing_up
    @student = Student.new
    render 'sing_up'
end

def create
    @student = Student.new
    @student.first_name = params[:student][:first_name]
    @student.last_name = params[:student][:last_name]
    @student.email = params[:student][:email]

    @student.salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
    @student.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(params[:student][:password], @student.salt)
    if @student.save
        redirect_to controller: 'singups', action: 'index'
    else
        render 'sing_up'
    end
end
```

and finnaly, this is model

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :password
    validates :first_name, :length => { minimum: 3, message: "first_name" }
    validates :last_name, :length => { minimum: 3, message: "last_name" }
    validates :email, :presence => { message: 'email' },
              :format => { with: /\A[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]+\z/ , message: 'email format' },
              :uniqueness => { message: 'uniqueness?' }
    validates :password, :confirmation => { message: 'password' },
                         :length => { minimum: 6, message: 'password length' }
end
```

Every time user enters password it fails on first validation `:confirmation => { message: 'password' }`, no matter what the password was.

If I remove `validates :password` part, everything works fine, but password that user enters is not validated.

Comment: Add your form code please. I suspect you're using `password_hash` in your form, when you should be using `password`? And yes, you can validate any field, regardless of whether it's a DB column or not.

Comment: I've added more information so you can check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're validating the user's `password` attribute but you never assign it a value in the first place. At the least, you need to add this to your controller code:

```
@student.password = params[:student][:password]
@student.password_confirmation = params[:student][:password_confirmation]
```

However, the more concise way is to use mass-assignment - get rid of all the @student.xxx = yyy and replace it with this:

```
@student = Studen.new(params[:student])
```

Then, move your password hashing method into the model and trigger it automatically before each save if the password attribute is present:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  before_save :hash_password, :if => proc{ |u| !u.password.blank? }
  # ....

  protected

  def hash_password
    self.salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
    self.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, salt)
  end
end
```

This way you don't have to do anything in the controller but this:

```
def create
  @student = Student.new(params[:student])
  if @student.save
    redirect_to controller: 'singups', action: 'index'
  else
    render 'sing_up'
  end
end
```

and have all other logic in your model, where it belongs.

EDIT: In order for mass assignment to work with the latest versions of Rails 3, you'll need to make the attributes you want to assign like that `attr_accessible`, like this:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password # but NOT the hash or salt!!

end
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the Railscast dealing with authentiction from scratch, all is explained here http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch

There is an updated cast here http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch-revised but you will need a subscription to view that (Well worth it IMO)

Comment: That was my idea, but I don't know where have I made a mistake

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the password entered by the user into an encrypted value, then compare the encrypted value with the value in password_hash to see if they match. That's how you validate that the user is the correct user. It doesn't matter if your model doesn't have a password field (it shouldn't) as you don't directly compare the value in password.

There are different ways of encrypting it but all that matters is how you encrypted the original password in the first place into the password_hash (how did you generate the 'password_hash'?). Use the same method to check new password submissions.

Comment: I'm not sure if you got me right. I need to validate password entered on 'sing up', not the password typed on login

Answer (score 0):

you can have a custom validation to check password and password_confirmation.

```
class User< ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :password, :password_confirmation 
  validate :valid_password

  def valid_password
    if password.blank? || password_confirmation.blank?
      errors.add(:password, 'password must not be blank')
    end

    if password != password_confirmation
      errors.add(:password, 'password and confirmation does not match')
    end
  end

end
```

this way, it checks if the password and confirmation exists and is present at the same time.

Comment: He's already using the built-in validations, and he's not asking on how to validate in the first place, but why the password is validated on registration.